# Angular2 OnInit data loading too slow causing undefined TypeError

Tags: javascript, angular

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

I used the same code from 'heroes' example to load a detail object in a single route. I kept getting this error because, I think, the data is not loaded before the view already started to render and that's why I am getting this error.

I had this problem to display "currentUser.name" which I solved by using `currentUser?.name` but in this case, it doesn't make sense to add to all the places of the object properties with '?'.

I have to spend more time in OnInit than what `heroes` example did. Because I need to fetch more stuff. So I know that the view just kicks in much earlier than the binding object `journal` is loaded.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUser().then( (user) => {
      this.currentUser = user;
      this.accountsService.getAccounts().then( (accounts) => {
        this.accounts = accounts;
        this.userAccounts = this.currentUser.accounts.map(
          accountId => this.accounts.find(
            elem => elem.id == new String(accountId)
          )
        );
        this.route.params
          .switchMap((params: Params) => this.journalService.getJournal(+params['id']))
          .subscribe( (journal) => {
            console.log("journal", journal);
            this.journal = journal;
          });
        });
      });
  }
```

How can I instruct the view to wait until the data is loaded before it starts to render itself?

Or is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: How is your `template`? Anyway, you can create a variable and set it to false on initialize... when your request is done, you set it to true. In view, you can simply use `ngIf` to check it it's true.

Comment: This works nicely, thanks!

Comment: @developer033 you should provide the comment as an answer so that OP can accept it

Comment: @echonax it's done  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap your `template` with a condition.

Steps:

1 - Create a variable and initializes it with a `falsy` value:

```
loaded: boolean = false;
```

2 - Set it to true when your request is finished:

```
this.route.params
.switchMap((params: Params) => this.journalService.getJournal(+params['id']))
.subscribe((journal) => {
  console.log("journal", journal);
  this.journal = journal;
  this.loaded = true; // -> here
});
```

3 - In your `template` use `*ngIf` to prevent errors:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="loaded">
  ... content
</ng-container>
```